# Object has no method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
```

This is my relevant HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="deleteConfirmationDialog" title="Confirm Withdrawl">
            Are you sure?
    </div>
    <div class="appl-appliedfor">
        <a class="deleteLink" href="/Applicant/WithdrawApplication/2">  
            <img class="appl-withdrawApplication"
            src="/Content/Images/Delete.png" alt="Withdraw Application" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/OnBoard/jquery-form-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Prime/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/OnBoard/OnBoardAll.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/OnBoard/ApplicantAll.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jqueryui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true
        });
    });

    $('.deleteLink').click(function(e) {
        $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes - Withdraw Application": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No - Do Nothing": function() {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog("open");
    });
</script>


    <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
        {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"28b6a62eb1fb42829a3191b7c3e270d4"}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://localhost:61108/d90608e9d0044daf98eb343c1b3769d7/browserLink" 
async="async"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everywhere I've searched the error is because you have to include jquery and jquery UI.
I've tried including JQuery UI with and without jquery.ui.dialog. No Luck.

What am I missing?  Thanks for reading.

**Edit**

The error points to the this line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog({
```

if I type $.dialog in the console I get undefined

If I reference jquery.ui.dialog.js there is the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a, b) { return new p.fn.init(a, b, c) } has no method 'widget'
```

otherwise there is no other error.

I get 200 OK's for everything.

I've removed the displayed javascript code in to its own file and referenced it last.  I have also moved the function that was outside the document.ready event function to inside this function, still getting the same error.

I can see jquery-ui and jquery in the Sources tab.

I don't understand why I can see jqueryui in the sources tab but typing $.dialog in the console results in undefined

Comment: Which line does the error point to?

Comment: What happens when you open the console and type "$.dialog"? What shows up?

Comment: why do you have `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js` and `jquery.ui.dialog.js`

Comment: is there any other error in the console

Comment: any 404 errors in network tab of browser console? just because script tag is there doesn't mean path is right. For example you have 2 different directory spellings for `jqueryui`

Comment: seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/6x3rK/2/

Answer (score 0):

Only code that doesn't use external libraries and code that doesn't use the DOM may be executed directly in a `<script>` tag.

If you search for DOM Elements directly in a `<script>` tag without waiting for the Document / DOM to be ready, the elements that you are searching for may not exist yet (in the DOM) or they may be incomplete.

Also using JavaScript methods directly in a `<script>` tag without waiting for the Document / DOM to be ready, the external files might have not been downloaded yet which means the methods from those external files might not exist yet.

In order to be sure that nothing like that occurs you need to put the code inside an event handler -- this ensures the code will be executed only after the event is triggered. The necessary event is `$(document).ready(event_handler_function)` also shorthanded as `$(event_handler_function).`.

Comment: I have updated my original post and have made the changes suggested, still no dice.